# Why does not runtime permissions dialog popup on specific phone?

Tags: java, android

**Splash.java:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Permission.checkPermission(this);
        ...
    }
```

**Permission.java:**

```
    public static final String[] permission = {
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.NFC,
            Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
    };
        
    public static void checkPermission(Activity act){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            for(String permission : permission) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, permission, 1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
    <manifest>
        <application>
            ...
        </application>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    </manifest>
```

---

I am getting this screen when the application is launched, and cannot proceed. I have to manually allow the permissions in the settings in order to use the app. The device on the screenshots is using Android 8.1 (Oreo). But on my other phone which is an Android 9 (Pie) it has pop-ups to allow or deny a permission. I was also expecting the same behavior on Oreo since runtime permissions are implemented from Marshmallow and later. What seems to be triggering the "Review Permissions" since I am not able to physically assess the device? *I do apologize for the screenshots, it was the clearest I can do.*

**Actual:**

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Translated ss]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

I have already tried using AVD running API 27 and it works, but on the phone, it does not.

Target & Compile SDK version: 27
Minimum SDK version: 16

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend to test on virtual devices (AVD manager), this also allows better screenshots ;-)
2. What's the compile and target SDK version?

Comment: Ah yes I have edited my question anyways, my target and compile SDK is 27 and the minimum is 16. I have also tried on a virtual device using android 8.1 and it works fine there. The 2nd screenshot is through google translate :-)